# mac.com addresses swallowing outbound emails to certain addresses

Tags: mac, email, gmail

I have a gmail account.  It's slowly come to my attention that whenever *anyone* with a mac.com domain sends an email to me, it gets entirely swallowed.  No one on the to, cc or bcc lines receives the email, regardless of their domain.  The sender receives no notification that the email was not sent.  Just gone.  Reply to all works the same way.

Since this problem is obviously on Apple's end, I've looked for contact info for them..and been unable to find anything that looks remotely human-monitored and is for the right..division..of Apple.

Anyone have any ideas about potential workarounds (I've tried adding/removing dots from my "published" email to no avail), or able to point me at contact info at Apple?  I apologize in advance as I know googling the correct thing would lead me straight to the solution...I just apparently have failed to figure out what the correct thing to google is.

Comment: I've never had a mac.com or me.com email so I can't be sure but perhaps it was [phased out?](https://www.macstories.net/news/sending-emails-from-mac-com-accounts-will-soon-be-impossible/)

Comment: @MC10 They only got discontinued for new users. Anyone that kept their account active will still have @ mac, and/or @ me depending on account age.

Comment: Are you sure *anyone* receives emails from this @mac.com email address?

Comment: @MichaelFrank The problem affects every mac address I've tested sending to my gmail account.  And yes, their email accounts otherwise work.